# asp.net core entity framework: No authenticationScheme was specified

Tags: entity-framework, azure-ad-b2c

Thi is my program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Datasync;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SkillbasedMiddleware.Db;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Configuration;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection1");

if (connectionString == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("DefaultConnection is not set");
}
  builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureADB2C"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to 
    // the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MigrationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Initialize the database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MigrationDbContext>();
    //await context.InitializeDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Configure and run the web service.
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

and this is my appsettings:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "yyyy",
    "Domain": "ccc.onmicrosoft.co",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Client"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

But it fails with:

InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

I am having trouble understanding this, because as to my understanding I am doing both of the things recommended.

Can anybody spot my issues?

This is meant to accept azure ad b2c requests.

thank you!